# How to store particular value from the JDBC Request response in the Custom Property using Script Assertion - SoapUI?

Tags: java, groovy, automation, soapui

In my testSuite, there are four requests have been added and the last step is **JdbcRequest**.

After running this **JdbcRequest** step, I'm trying to get the **phone number** from the response. For that I have written the following script in the **Script Assertion** of **JdbcRequest** step.

```
import groovy.util.*
import groovy.lang.*
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.*

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( context.responseAsXml )

def pNo = responseHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Results/*:ResultSet/*:Row/*:PHONE_NUMBER")
log.info pNo 

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo) // Not storing in the property
```

I will execute the three requests using the **Groovy Script** i.e. first step.
After completion of the execution (**JdbcRequest**), its not storing the **phone number** in **Script Assertion** and its showing as **NULL**. I tried the following ways but no luck.

```
//def x = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo)
//context.testCase.project.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo)
//context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo)
//testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo)
```

Your suggestion please.

Thanks

Comment: Before answering this, does the line 'log.info pNo' return the phone number?

Comment: Is it possible to show the jdbc response(even sample would do)?

Comment: If 'log.info pNo' is printing null, then the text "PHONE_NUMBER" doesn't exist under (.../*:Row). I suggest you check the node name once.
n I wonder how you used testRunner in a script assertion 0.o!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there....

The line below is a set command, and is the one to use, but you're assigning it to a var....

```
//def x = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo)
```

Instead, change it to

```
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo",pNo)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried that too but No luck and its showing NULL

Comment: But firstly, does the line 'log.info pNo' return the phone number?

Comment: If I run Script Assertion alone, it prints Phone Number where as while executing along with the other TestSteps, phone number is not storing into the Custom Property .

Comment: Is the custom property created?  Have you tried writing a string to the property to verify?  E.g. messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("JdbcPhoneNo","propIsWorking");

Comment: Tried like this. context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("PhoneNo","Welcome")...The string itself not printing.

Comment: Hello, I might see what's happening here.  My suggestion writes to custom properties of the Test Case.  You approach writes to the custom properties of the Test Suite.  I have just tested both approaches in my SoapUI and they both work, but they write to different places and I thought you might be looking at the test case props when you're actually writing to test suite.

Comment: Tried to access that property value like this: String phn = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PhoneNo") - prints EMPTY. JdbcRequest Script Assertions always gets failed and if I open the Script Assertion dialog and then close it by clicking OK then the property gets a values and assertion got PASSED... Why?

Comment: FYI: String phn = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PhoneNo") used in the Groovy Script test step to access messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("PhoneNo","propIsWorking");

Comment: Two Points.  Firstly, context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue is writing to the test suite node in your project, but context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PhoneNo") is getting the value from the test case node.  Test Suite and Test Case are two different things.  It looks like you are writing to one place but trying to get a value from somewhere else.  Secondly, why does your assertion pass, do you have an 'assert' line in your script assertion?

Comment: In the Script Assertion of JdbcRequest, these are the code I have used.         
<imported packages>
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( context.responseAsXml )
def rowidPhone2 = context.expand('${#TestCase#rowidPhone1}')
String contactNo = responseHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Results/*:ResultSet/*:Row/*:PHONE_NUMBER")
log.info "Script Assertion :" + contactNo
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("PhoneNo","propIsWorking");

Comment: And is that working?  By that, I mean is the value getting set as you expect?  Can you see the value in the SoapUI?

Comment: Its working now as I have replaced the line def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( context.responseAsXml ) to def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(  messageExchange.responseContent   )

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for the above issue.

I used like this

```
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(  messageExchange.responseContent   )
```

instead of `def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( context.responseAsXml )`

The value is storing into the property for each execution.